# How does Package Manager Console know which connection string to use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I have a website application. Depending on the `IsDemoSite` setting in my *appsettings.json* file, the application uses one of two different database connection strings. (One for my main site, and another for our demo site.)

I also have a class library that contains all the Entity Framework models and migrations.

In the Package Manager Console, I set the *Default project* to the class library.

[image: Default project setting in Package Manager Console]

Then, I can run the `add-migration` and `update-database` commands on that class library. But here's the kicker: The `IsDemoSite` setting for my main application determines which database these commands work with.

How on Earth does Package Manager Console know to what connection string is used by my main application based on the current setting? I'm not running the main application. Package Manager Console is not using the main application as the default project. How the heck does it know which connection string to use?

Comment: Hint: create an instance of your dbcontext using the parameterless constructor. Which database it connects to? Which setting it uses?

Answer (score 4):

When you run and `add-migration` or an `update-database` command, Package Manager Console will look for the Startup project of your solution and use it as "entry point" for these commands.

Probably inside your `Startup.cs` class you have the database context injected using the connection string that is stored in your appsettings.json.

I believe you have something like that:

```
string connectionString;

bool isDemoSite = configuration.GetValue<string>("IsDemoSite");

if(isDemoSite)
    connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("mainSite");
else
    connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("demoSite");

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

`add-migration` and `update-database` uses this very same code to determinate against which database it will execute, is something like your application is beign executed to allow this commands to run.

That's also the reason you need some EntityFramework packages installed in your startup project.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering which appsettings.json would the application use if i used Package Manager Console from Visual Studio 2022. I had `appsettings.json`, `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`, each with different connection string.

The one used was `appsettings.Development.json`.

Comment: This depends on environment used. Usually it is managed with launchsettings.json for local development in VS and is not guaranteed to be set to Development.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).